# HTTP 503 – Service Unavailable – craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException [installation]

Tags: installation

I tried installing Craft 3.0 using composer (php composer.phar create-project craftcms/craft PATH)

And when I try to access the /web folder it's giving me the following error. I have tried removing the folder and installing it afresh again. I am currently using MAMP on my osx localhost.

> 1. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php at line 498
> 2. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php at line 175 – craft\web\Application::_processInstallRequest(craft\web\Request)
> 3. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 386 – craft\web\Application::handleRequest(craft\web\Request)
> 4. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/web/index.php at line 21 – yii\base\Application::run()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very likely it cannot connect to the database; that's typically what the `503` error is about:

https://httpstatuses.com/503

...so check the credentials in your `.env` file, and make sure that the version of MySQL that your website is using is the internal MAMP MySQL, and not the system-wide MySQL (if any).

This video may help you: [Installing Craft CMS v3 with MAMP Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqSp-CvKwJM&t=5s)

...and also a discussion of local development environments we had here might be of interest as well: [Shootout at the Local Dev Corral](https://devmode.fm/episodes/shootout-at-the-local-dev-corral)

Answer (score 10):

If you've just imported a database, it could mean your project.yaml is out of sync in your environment.

I fixed this by running the CLI command:

```
./craft project-config/sync
```

Comment: What should you do if you don't have access to the command line tools?

Comment: You can also sync changes in the project config by visiting the control panel in your browser (usually `/admin`). Click the "Sync changes" button at the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

For those creating a fresh install using [Craft CMS Nitro](https://craftcms.com/docs/nitro/2.x/) and its `nitro create` command, don't forget to run the the Setup Wizard as a final step, as described in [Step 6: Run the Setup Wizard](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/installation.html#step-6-run-the-setup-wizard), from the Craft Docs:

Either run the setup from the admin dashboard, which redirects to:  yoursite.com/admin/install

Or you can run `nitro php craft setup` and complete setup from the terminal.

This will populate the database with Craft's tables & data and should address the 503 error.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that Apaches `mod_rewrite` wasn't enabled and Crafts `.htaccess`-file was ignored while the config `omitScriptNameInUrls => true` was set.

Looking at the code from the stacktrace, it looks like Craft was unable to determine that the request actually was for the CP and it didn't allow the installation to start, throwing the Error and returning 503 instead.

So if your URLs don't work without `index.php?p=` in front of them and you're serving via Apache, chances are that you need to enable `mod_rewrite` and then Craft will allow you to install.

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

If this doesn't help, make sure that overriding the server-config via `.htaccess` is allowed for your `VirtualHost`. Here is an example configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

  DocumentRoot /app/web

  <Directory '/app/web'>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a site where in `general.php`, the staging section had the `'isSystemLive' => false,`

It was driving me batty why I could only see the front-end if logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime I run into this issue, it's either the database settings are incorrect or I need to run composer install, so I am posting this as an answer because I am sure I will end up back at this question trying to figure out what I didn't do right.

Comment: ./craft project-config/sync did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had to answer a craft prompt about db backup on `/admin` page before I was able to access any other pages